# How to avoid race conditions with mongoengine (make atomic changes to ListFields and DictFields)

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I'm using mongoengine and seem to be running into some potential race condition incidents. As a simple example we have code that works something like this

```
def changeModel(newitemL, olditemD)
    model.randomList.append(newitemL)
    model.randomDict.pop(olditemD,None)
    model.save()
```

So if two users are trying to perform this action with different items then sometimes it will only show 1 users changes to the saved model. Is there a way I'm suppose to be changing ListFields and DictFields atomically to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing a save, it would be better to do an update instead eg:

```
model.update(push__randomList=newitemL, pop__randomDict)
```

That way you will only impact those elements atomically.

Currently mongoengine is simple and naive when doing a save on list / dict fields eg:

```
model.randomList.append(newitemL)

# Converts to a set of the whole list:
model.update(set__randomList=model.randomList)
```

Comment: What if I were adding something to a dict? Say a new key? I know I could do something like model.update(set__randomDict__key=value) but I ran into problems when key was a variable. How would I handle that?

Comment: Well update just takes `kwargs` so if dynamic just set to a dictionary eg: `kwargs["set__randomDict__%s" % key] = newItem` and then pass as kwargs: `model.update(**kwargs)`

Comment: The method you suggested doesn't seem like it can be used to remove a key from a dictionary...it works for the list operation though